# Data type change by in select from view

Tags: mysql, sqldatatypes

I would like to ask if there is any possibility to change data type from VARCHAR to YYYYMM by select from view.  I have column in this type 201805.

Comment: There is no data type `YYYYMM`.

Comment: Sorry I meant to date data type

Comment: There is no datatype with just year and month.